# How to write a file with variable "key" and its position?

Tags: java, randomaccessfile

I would like to write indexed file (indexed.ind), and I need two variables. One variable is "key" witch is written in file.dat, the other variable is "position", that should be the position where "key" is written in file.dat. Here is my code, but the problem is that position always is zero.

```
rafObj = new RandomAccessFile(fileName, "rw");
rafObj.seek(0);    
while(rafObj.getFilePointer()<rafObj.length())
        {
            posicion = rafObj.getFilePointer();
            clave = rafObj.readUTF();
        }

 rafObj.seek(rafObj.length());
 rafObj.writeUTF(clave);
 rafObj.writeLong(posicion);
```

Comment: I see that your navigating to the end of the file to write. why the loop then ?

Comment: Because I need to reed all the file, and the user could insert "clave" several times

Comment: I need to read sorry